# Account creation review step - post form validation

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation

I have a question that has been bugging me for quite a while now. I am working on a project that has a form tied to a payment gateway. This form is validated and once valid after the user clicks 'Sign Up', the credit card number is automatically charged (without review).

I am trying to add an intermediate step that is pretty much a summary of the amount that is going to be charged and the information that is going to be used for account creation. I am debating between the two approaches:

1) Post data is posted to an additional page before the account is created (and credit card is charged), from this page if all information is correct (in the users eyes), users click Sign Up and then the account is finally created - this would probably require re-posting the variables or creating session variables...

2) Use JavaScript to hide the form 'on submit', and show the initially hidden, review container, using javascript, which will set html fields of the hidden review screen before showing it, from here when a user confirms all information is correct, the account is created / credit card is charged, and we did it without session / reposting of variables.

However, I noticed a lot of websites tend to use approach number 1 from the above. I was wondering why is this, and is approach number 2 a decent way to tackle this problem?

I appreciate any advice, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use javascript when it is not needed. The other way you can confirm on your server if people are backing out without completing the process, and you have a log of what they did if anything does go wrong, the other way you only know if they have completed.

Comment: Method 1 gives the developers more possibilities to prevent tampering the data and makes it possible to 'restore' a page after a connection failed for example.

Comment: I would advise that you **NOT** give them the option to review the credit card, as it will probably violate the TOS with the payment gateway and you will also not be within PCI compliance.  typing CC num, exp, ccv code is hard enough on the end user as it is, and they will probably never review it.. If they get the cc wrong, no big deal, let them try again http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pcifaqs.php#1

Comment: I never planned to give users the option to review sensitive information like credit card number / CVV, etc.. Its not about reviewing the credit card info. It is about giving users an additional opportunity to review the amount that is to be charged to their card and the information that is going to be used for their account.

Comment: Handling sensitive business logic, i.e. stuff that's happening during the payment process is a thing people generally prefer doing server-side, I think. That way noone can read your code, not even minimized Javascript. That might be a reason for approach #1 being more popular.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. How is setting hidden HTML elements with the same user values that were just filled out on the form, *within the same page*, then showing it, more risky than transmitting it to an additional page, for review? ...I suppose it is the same amount of risk as the information getting intercepted directly from the input field, how is it not?